# Capturing window events using AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK

Tags: java, swing, awt

For capturing window events on global level, I am doing

```
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
            System.out.println(event);
            System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Window.getWindows()));
        }
    }, AWTEvent.WINDOW_EVENT_MASK);
```

However, when an internal frame window is opened, I am not receiving any event. Also, `Window.getWindows()` is not returning internal frame windows.

1. **How can I capture the events (opening and closing) from InternalFrame windows on a global level?**
2. When I try to narrow down the events using `AWTEvent.WINDOW_STATE_EVENT_MASK`, I am not receiving any event. I am specifically interested in Window opening and closing event. **How can I achieve this?**

Answer (score 1):

For `JInternalFrame` opening and close, no `WindowEvent` is pushed, because it is not a `Window` child. Using the `AWTEvent.CONTAINER_EVENT_MASK` parameter in `AWTEventListener` you'll receive `ContainerEvent[COMPONENT_ADDED]` and `ContainerEvent[COMPONENT_REMOVED]` for adding and removing the `JInternalFrames` respectively:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(new AWTEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {
        System.out.println(event);
    }
}, AWTEvent.CONTAINER_EVENT_MASK);
```